# How is this C# dictionary initialization correct?

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization

I stumbled upon the following and I'm wondering why it didn't raise a syntax error.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["Id"] = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ["Tribes"] = new List<int> { 4, 5 },
    ["MyA"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Name"] = "Solo",
        ["Points"] = 88
    }
    ["OtherAs"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Points"] = 1999
        }
    }
};
```

Notice that the "," is missing between the "MyA", and "OtherAs".

This is where the confusion happens:

1. The code compiles.
2. The final dictionary "dict" contains only three elements: "Id", "Tribes", and "MyA".
3. The value for all except "MyA" are correct,
4. "MyA" takes the declared value for "OtherAs", while its original value is ignored.

Why isn't this illegal? Is this by design?

Comment: Are you missing a comma between the entries Mya and OtherAs or this is exactly as you want it?

Comment: @Steve that's what he asking about. I pasted this into sharplab and it looks like initially `OtherAs` gets added as a key into what *would be* the `MyA` dictionary. (Name=Solo, Points=88 *plus* OtherAs=List<Dictionary <string, object>>) except it then *never assigns it*. Instead it places the list of dicts, now only containing the single Points=1999 entry into the `MyA` slot overriding what one would think belongs there.

Comment: Link was too long to paste in first comment. This is strange indeed. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4qkDchdRAzOVqQMKkDehpP5TGVALIAKAJSduvKQDcAhlFIATAJZgALqQC8pAHYwA7qQAiqtcog75ATwA8FYgBpSEYACsY6gHyEuBKQG0AIgBJRUCAXS1SAHEAV2VFADoAOQM4hLEHSR4ggBUoZWAYAGcIqL1DABllYrUbZR01T05SFCcAVlIAXyy/XiDBKwBBMu0K41NzSyhbeycXdy9siT6pHMDk2QBbGFHSQIBlCAAbCEDetf7AgAUIBrVSyO0ADmflruWggHk1AAsYKBDR7lAykaq1GwmdRTax2HCOZxuDxNbyrFaXHjjKFmCywuaIxZNZZSXwYtZBW73YHaHAATnpxN4HzRzK6tBZhC6QA==

Comment: Yes, I have tested it with LinqPad and got the same result. Not sure what's going on here. Let's see if some C# guru could shed some light here.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug

Comment: If you change the first dictionary to `<string, string> and modify Points to `"88"` you then get a compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>' to 'string'" which actually helped me figure out the answer!

Comment: @OlegI I dont think its a compiler bug. Many good explanations already provided in answers. But if you try `var test = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
  ["Name"] = "Solo",
  ["Points"] = 88
}["OtherAs"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Points"] = 1999
    }
};` will explain it further.

Comment: IDEs and related tools can help with these. In your code, Resharper warns at the place of the missing comma: "Assignment expression inside member initializer looks suspicious. Comma is probably missing." (it's the `PossiblyMissingIndexerInitializerComma` [inspection for C#](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Inspections_CSHARP.html)).

Comment: @Steve, it was meant to be a syntax error on my part. While running my tests, i noticed there were missing values in the dictionary, so looking over the initialization i realized the "," was missing - which is where i got confused why the compiler didn't flag my omission.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The missing comma makes all the difference. It causes the indexer `["OtherAs"]` to be applied on this dictionary:

```
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["Name"] = "Solo",
    ["Points"] = 88
}
```

So essentially you're saying:

```
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["Name"] = "Solo",
    ["Points"] = 88
}["OtherAs"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Points"] = 1999
    }
};
```

Note that this is an assignment expression (`x = y`). Here `x` is dictionary with "Name" and "Points", indexed with `"OtherAs"` and `y` is the `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. An assignment expression evaluates to the value being assigned (`y`), which is the list of dictionaries.

The result of this whole expression is then assigned to the key "MyA", which is why "MyA" has the list of dictionaries.

You can confirm that this is what's happening by changing the type of the dictionary `x`:

```
new Dictionary<int, object>
{
    [1] = "Solo",
    [2] = 88
}
// compiler error saying "can't convert string to int"
// so indeed this indexer is applied to the previous dictionary
["OtherAs"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Points"] = 1999
    }
}
```

Here is your code, but reformatted and some parentheses added to illustrated how the compiler has parsed it:

```
["MyA"] 
= 
(
    (
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Name"] = "Solo",
            ["Points"] = 88
        }["OtherAs"] 
    )
    = 
    (
        new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
        {
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["Points"] = 1999
            }
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: It was changing the dictionary's value type from `object` to `string` that gave me a similar error message and the *aha* moment that sparked the answer. Seems you beat me to it--I blame typing the answer on my phone :-p

Answer (score 20):

What's happening here is that you are creating a dictionary and then indexing into it. The result of the indexer/assignment expression is then returned and that is what is getting assigned into the `MyA` dictionary slot.

This:

```
["MyA"] = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{
   ["Name"] = "Solo",
   ["Points"] = "88" 
}
["OtherAs"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
   new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       ["Points"] = 1999
   }
}
```

Can be split out into the following psuedo-code:

```
var temp = new Dictionary<string, object>
{ 
   ["Name"] = "Solo", 
   ["Points"] = 88 
};
// indexed contains result of assignment
var indexed = temp["OtherAs"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
   new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
      ["Points"] = 1999
   }
};
// value is set to result of assignment from previous step
["MyA"] = indexed;
// temp is discarded
```

The result of assigning to the indexer of the second dictionary is returned (the assignment returns the value assigned/right hand side) That dictionary is a temporary local that just "disappears into the ether". The result of the indexer (the list of dictionaries) is what is placed into the main dictionary in the end.

This is a weird case, which is made easier to fall into due to the use of `object` as the type of the dictionary values.